# Find k-th element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

i am trying to figure out how this code works.

```
function Kth_greatest_in_array(arr, k) {

  for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    let max_index = i;
    const tmp = arr[i];


    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[max_index]) {
        max_index = j;
      }
    }

    arr[i] = arr[max_index];
    arr[max_index] = tmp;
  }

  return arr[k - 1];
}

console.log(Kth_greatest_in_array([1,2,6,4,5], 3))
```

As you can see the goal is to find third biggest value. But i don know how the second loop works. Could you explain it to me step by step. For example, what is the meaning of veriable j, especially why they typed let j = i +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method basically performs an in-place sort of the `arr` array (but only "k" times - not a full sort), then returns the element (from the now partially sorted array) at index `k-1`.

The inner `for` loop looks through the remaining (unsorted) portion of the array to find the index of the item with the highest value:

```
if (arr[j] > arr[max_index]) {
   max_index = j;
}
```

The specific statement you were asking about, `let j = i + 1`, means "declare a new variable, `j`, and set its initial value to one greater than the current iteration of the outer `for` loop". "`j`" is arbitrary and could be any valid identifier, it's just often used by convention when you have nested `for` loops since the outermost loop usually uses  `i` (which is presumably short for "index").

At the end of each iteration of the outer `for` loop, these lines swap array elements so that this element is in the correct position:

```
arr[i] = arr[max_index];
arr[max_index] = tmp;
```

If you're curious to really understand the inner workings of a method like this, I'd highly encourage you to step through it with a debugger - it can be a great learning experience. Even just the tried-and-true method of sprinkling some temporary `console.log` statements can help illuminate what's going on (e.g., print the state of `arr` and `max_index` after every outer and inner loop iteration).